# Implementing factory in Scalatest

Tags: scala, testing, factory, traits, scalatest

I have the following trait:

```
trait TraitToTest{
    def doSome(): Unit
}
```

and some implementations

```
class Impl1 extends TraitToTest
class Impl2 extends TraitToTest
class Impl3 extends TraitToTest
//...
```

I have some general contracts for `TraitToTest` each implementation has to adhere to. I can describe the contract as follows:

```
class TraitTest extends FunSpec with Matchers{

   describe("TraitTest general contracts"){
       it("should test contract 1"){
           val impl = //some impl of TraitToTest
           //the test
       }
   }
}
```

The problem is I don't want to duplicate the `TraitToTest` general contracts for each implementation of `TraitToTest`. I just want to supply the implementation instance as a sort of factory or so...

Is it possible to do in `Scalatest`?

Answer (score 3):

Another way to do it is to generate appropriate tests.

```
class TraitToTest extends FunSpec {
  val testCases =
    List(
      ("Impl1", new Impl1()), 
      ("Impl2", new Impl2()), 
      ("Impl3", new Impl3())
    )

  testCases.foreach {
    case (name, impl) =>
      describe(name) {
        it("should fulfill contract 1") {
          // tests for impl go here
        }
      }
  }
```

Output of `sbt test`:

```
[info] Impl1
[info] - should fulfill contract 1
[info] Impl2
[info] - should fulfill contract 1
[info] Impl3
[info] - should fulfill contract 1
```

I'm not sure if this is a known pattern, but personally I use this to write most of my tests - find the contract I want to test and create test cases for various sets of inputs and expected outputs.

Comment: You can also make it closer to factories: `("Impl1", () => new Impl1())` and then call `impl()` in the test. Especially useful if the types are mutable...

Answer (score 2):

Transform `TraitTest` into an abstract  class:

```
abstract class TraitTest extends FunSpec with Matchers {

  val impl: TraitToTest

  describe("TraitTest general contracts"){
    it("should test contract 1"){
      impl.doSome()
    }
  }

}
```

The implementation suites will instantiate the respective trait:

```
class Impl1TestSuite extends TraitTest {

  override val impl = new Impl1()

}
```